# Nodejs 6.9.1 y Mongodb 3.0 ¿Por qué al enviar mi petición Post no me da respuesta el servidor?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy haciendo un Rest con Node, estoy usando la aplicación Postman para enviar las peticiones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al darle Send, se queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego de un rato se detiene por esperar demasiado tiempo una respuesta.

El código es el siguiente:

Este es mi modelo  **models/product.js**

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const ProductSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  picture: String,
  price: {type: Number, default: 0},
  category: {type: String, enum: ['computers', 'phones', 'accesories']},
  description: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

Y este es mi archivo principal, como el index pero lo llamo **app.js**

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const Product = require('./models/product');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// Declarar el middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Escucha de peticiones
app.get('/api/product', (req, res) => {
  res.send(200, {products: []});
})

app.get('/api/product/:productId', (req, res) => {
  
})

app.post('/api/product', (req, res) => {
  // bodyParser nos permite acceder al cuerpo más fácil
  //console.log('POST /api/product');
  //console.log(req.body);

  let product = new Product();
  product.name = req.body.name;
  product.picture = req.body.picture;
  product.price = req.body.price;
  product.category = req.body.category;
  product.description = req.body.description;

  console.log(product);
  product.save((err, productStored) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar en la DB: ${err}'})
      
      res.status(200).send({product: productStored})
  });
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`API REST corriendo en http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

Como se muestra, hago un console.log al product que se supone adquiere los valores enviados por posts, los cuales se asignan correctamente, se crea el documento y se autogenera su _id:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero algo está pasando en el save. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: funciona https://github.com/scotch-io/node-api

Comment: Es muy Interesante lo que estas haciendo, estoy en algo parecido pero con Meteor y Node con Soket.IO

Comment: @Rastalovely Sí, estoy siguiendo este tutorial por si te llama la atención: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcO5WES8j6s&index=7&list=PLUdlARNXMVkk7E88zOrphPyGdS50Tadlr Es de los mejores que explican nodejs, entendí muchas cosas y maneras diferentes de codificar, por ejemplo en vez de los callbacks function (err, obj){} coloca (err,obj) => {} y prácticas de codificación similares. Yo le puse ; por la costumbre, pero él, no. Saludos

Comment: @Rastalovely por cierto que el error era que no estaba estableciendo la conexión a la DB :v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya vi mi error, es de novatada:

Lo que pasa es que no estaba estableciendo mi conexión con mongo -.- lo sé, algo muy tonto, igual lo dejo para si otro novato llega al mismo error :P

sólo al final de **app.js** en lugar de

```
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`API REST corriendo en http://localhost:${port}`)


})
```

Lo edité para agregar primero la conexión, y si la conexión es exitosa entonces en el callback coloco el listen:

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shop', (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Conexion a la DB establecida')
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`API REST corriendo en http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Y ahora sí me está devolviendo el documento almacenado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso era todo :v